# Is there a vendor-neutral tool/driver to program a mouse's middle button (wheel click ) to behave as it does in Linux - paste what's selected?

Tags: mouse

Linux XWindow system has a pretty convenient (IMHO) feature - instead of using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V all the time, I can just select what I want to copy-paste and wheel-click where I want to paste it. Can I reach the same behaviour in Windows XP without using a mouse vendor-specific driver/tool?

Comment: shorten your title...please.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two that were featured on Life Hacker:

- [AutoclipX copies and pastes text with one click of the-mouse](http://lifehacker.com/#!5779868/autoclipx-copies-and-pastes-text-with-one-click-of-the-mouse)
- [Copy and paste quicker using your mouse with True X-Mouse Gizmo](http://lifehacker.com/#!294701/copy-and-paste-quicker-using-your-mouse-with-true-x+mouse-gizmo) (note I've had compatibility issues with Vista/Windows 7.)

Answer (score 0):

Try X-Mouse Button control

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm